# Quickly install / upgrade Shopware security Plugin in a composer managed store

Tags: shopware6

There are critical security issues in Shopware 6 pre 6.4.18.1.

We manage our shops via Composer and due to incompatible 3rd party plugins cannot upgrade to 6.4.18.1 quickly.

Now there is https://store.shopware.com/swag136939272659f/shopware-6-sicherheits-plugin.html?number=Swag136939272659

What is a recommended way to install / upgrade this plugin.

We have the following options:

1. Activate Shopware store and install the plugin using the store (after login on the Shopware account, which can cause complications with staging URLs)
2. Download the plugin ZIP manually, for example from a Wildcard account and upload it manually
3. Install via composer, run through a full deploy process but don't update Shopware just yet but just the Security plugin.

How are others handling the Security plugin upgrades? Is there an officially recommended way?

Answer (score 4):

I prefer handling all Store plugins via composer, so in your case requiring `store.shopware.com/swagplatformsecurity` and deploying that (along with a `plugin:install` or `plugin:update`).

As you mentioned, using the included Store breaks down in deployed/version-controlled environments.
You could also extract the ZIP into `custom/plugins` and deploy that, but then this would be an exception of your otherwise composer-managed project.